# Is the documentation of str.strip() misleading?

Tags: python, string, strip

The [documentation for str.strip()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) says:

> Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters
>   removed. The chars argument is a string specifying the set of
>   characters to be removed. **If omitted or None, the chars argument
>   defaults to removing whitespace**

But in reality, if the parameter is omitted, not only whitespace are removed, but also carriage returns, new lines and line feeds:

```
> 'hello\f\r\n'.strip()
'hello'
```

Comment: No it isn't. Newlines, CRs and LFs are whitespace. Wikipedia says: "In computer programming, whitespace is any character or series of characters that represent _horizontal_ _or_ _vertical_ space in typography." (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitespace_character)

Comment: Carriage returns, new lines and line feeds are generally to be considered whitespace characters.

Comment: Tabs and vertical tabs as well.

Comment: I agree with those comments, but the doc could be more specific and I can see how you might have this question.  [ABNF](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5234), for instance, specifies WSP as only a space or horizontal tab.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not misleading.

As commenters have pointed out, newlines, carriage returns, and linefeeds are whitespace.

So when the doc says "if omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace", we expect newlines etc. to be removed. It would be confusing and bizarre if it worked otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

**No the documentation of str.strip() not  misleading**

**according to documentation:**

If omitted or None, the chars argument defaults to removing whitespace
`print('    Hello      \n\n'.strip())`
**Output:**
`Hello`

Return a copy of the string with the leading and trailing characters removed
The chars argument is a string specifying the set of characters to be removed
`mix_txt = "***rrtt++.....Hello....---"
v_str = mix_txt.strip("-*rt+.")
print(v_str)`
**Output:**
`Hello`

if you use this way strip() will only remove 'H' character. Not anything else 
`print('HelloH\f\n\n.'.strip('H'))`
**Output:**
`elloH` with dot(.) at the start of line after skipping one line due to \n\n

**overall output**

[image]